TextInput (IOS) : maxLength & multiline true = onChangeText multiple call
During different tests I realized that when my text reaches the maximum size, with multiline={true} and maxLength={200} onChangeText is called several times and this has the effect of modifying the initial value given, example here

Waiting for the api response could make the keyboard seem slow and since the user will still be able to type, when the api result finally was updated in state it would give you weird behavior. I think it would be better if you decoupled the global state from the textinput and only update it after the api call (demo):
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Card, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import { useState, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';
import useFetchData from './useFetchData';
import stringSimilarity from 'string-similarity';

// simulate your use case of updating the text input with data
const initialString = 'An aple mobile which is nothing like aple';
// then we set the string to the closest matching product description
const getBestMatch = (str, list) => {
  return stringSimilarity.findBestMatch(
    str,
    list.map((l) => l.description)
  ).bestMatch.target;
};

export default function App() {
  const [list, listLoading, listError] = useFetchData();
  const [description1, setDescription1] = useState(initialString);
  const [description2, setDescription2] = useState(initialString);
  // storing the description separately from the textinput
  const apiDescription = useMemo(() => {
    if (list.length > 0 && description2.length)
      return getBestMatch(description2, list);
    return '';
  }, [description2, list]);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.input}>
        <Text>
          After typing the first character this textinput becomes hard to use
        </Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Weirdness"
          value={description1}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            const bestMatch = getBestMatch(text, list);
            console.log(bestMatch);
            setDescription1(bestMatch || text);
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.input}>
        <Text>This text input remains usable</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Some text"
          value={description2}
          onChangeText={setDescription2}
        />
        <Text>
          Updated text:{'\n'}
          {apiDescription}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  input: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

